# Populate route params with resolved data in angular ui-route

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state, meanjs

Give the following code:

```
$stateProvider
      .state('app.users', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/users',
        templateUrl: 'views/users.html',
        resolve: {
          userId: Users => Users.lastUserSelected()
        },
      })
      .state('app.users.questions', {
        url: '/:userId/questions',
        templateUrl: 'views/questions.html',
        controller: 'UsersQuestionsCtrl',
        resolve: {
          questions: (userId) => Questions.getAll(userId)
        }
      })
```

When I transit to the app.users.questions state, everything goes ok, but the URL in the browser ends up being like mydomain.com/users//questions (notice the double forward slash // in the route, there's no userId)

Seems like the user ID resolved from the parent state is not populated in child route, or something alike. I think I'm missing a key concept here.

I would like to achieve a URL like mydomain.com/users/USERID/questions.

I've been through many ui-router guides but couldn't figure this out, any help is really appreciated.

I'm populating my sideBar menu using the addMenuItem and addMenuSubItem methods from the MEANJS project.

```
Menus.addMenuItem('sidebar', {
            state: 'app.users',
            type: 'dropdown',
            iconClass: 'fa fa-comments',
            position: 4,
            roles: ['*']
        });

Menus.addSubMenuItem('sidebar', 'app.users', {
            state: 'app.user-questions'
        });
```

Notes:

1- It doesn't matter the previous state, wherever state I come from... it's not related at all to the user, so passing the :userId from all the possible  previous states sounds wrong to me. I'm just using USERS and QUESTIONS as an example here but those are not the entities i'm working with in my actual project.

2 - Im using [MEANJS](https://meanjs.org/) seed project

Comment: How are you calling that state? Using $stete.go() or using ui-sref ??

Comment: using ui-sref. Not by election but because I'm using the MEANJS addMenuItem function.

Comment: could you please add that part of your code to the question.

Comment: Add the code to populate the menu.

Comment: As far as I can see, you are not specifying the userId.
I was looking for something like ui-sref="app.user-questions({userId: userIdValue})"  in your link reference.

Comment: ui-sref="app.users.questions({'userId': userIdValue})"?

Comment: The thing is... what I want to achieve is that in case no userId is passed from the previous state (which will be the case in most circumstances in my app), the parent state should resolve and select at least one random user before entering any of the child states. That part is working, the lastUserSelected service works fine and the user is selected. But the URL route is not well formed.